# Jupyter Lab: Precompile error for kernel 1.0 after adding kernel 1.3

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, jupyter-lab

On a Ubuntu 18.04 Intel system I have Jupyter Lab running smoothly with a Julia 1.0.4 kernel.  I would like to add the 1.3 kernel.  I download the 64bit linux binary from the official download site.  I ran the binary, and gave the commands Using Pkg;Pkg.add("IJulia");Pkg.build("IJulia") with no errors.

When I run Jupyter Lab and select a 1.0.4 notebook, the system tries to precompile IJulia and get the follow error:

```
[ Info: Precompiling IJulia [7073ff75-c697-5162-941a-fcdaad2a7d2a]
ERROR: LoadError: InitError: error compiling __init__: could not load library "/home/cc/.julia/packages/ZMQ/ABGOx/deps/usr/lib/libzmq.so"
/home/cc/.julia/packages/ZMQ/ABGOx/deps/usr/lib/libzmq.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
Stacktrace:
 [1] _include_from_serialized(::String, ::Array{Any,1}) at ./loading.jl:633
 [2] _require_search_from_serialized(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at ./loading.jl:713
 [3] _require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:937
 [4] require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:858
 [5] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:853
 [6] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [7] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1044
 [8] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [9] top-level scope at none:2
 [10] eval at ./boot.jl:319 [inlined]
 [11] eval(::Expr) at ./client.jl:393
 [12] top-level scope at ./none:3
during initialization of module ZMQ
in expression starting at /home/cc/.julia/packages/IJulia/F1GUo/src/IJulia.jl:36
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile IJulia [7073ff75-c697-5162-941a-fcdaad2a7d2a] to /home/cc/.julia/compiled/v1.0/IJulia/nfu7T.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
 [2] compilecache(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1203
 [3] _require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:960
 [4] require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:858
 [5] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:853
 [6] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [7] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1044
 [8] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [9] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:266
 [10] _start() at ./client.jl:425
in expression starting at /home/cc/.julia/packages/IJulia/F1GUo/src/kernel.jl:1
[I 20:20:45.777 LabApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
```

Kernel 1.3 notebooks appear to run ok.

Any ideas on how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this problem by replacing the 1.0.4 kernel with 1.0.5, which is the long term support kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you installed julia 1.0.4 as 32-bit. You can check this by starting julia and type `sizeof(Int)`. If it returns 4, then it is 32-bit binary. When you installed julia 1.3.0 and IJulia, it overwrote the 32-bit libzmq.so library with a 64-bit one which cannot be used in julia 1.0.4.
If this is the case, I would recommend you to replace to replace 32-bit julia 1.0.4 by the 64-bit version.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I am running a 64bit version